# How to set an image based on iphone platform in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm moving my application from 3.x to 4.x as I prepare for the app store and found that I need to have 2 copies of all my custom pngs - my question is how can I determine what img to show and when.  Example - how do I know to show the Find.png vs the Find@2x.png

Is it "safe" or "correct" to look for 4.x specific apis or does the iphone have a way to determine what platform you are on at runtime?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use standard APIs, the phone handles grabbing the @2x version when necessary. For example if you use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Find.png"];` and run on an iPhone 4, it would load Find@2x.png automatically.

Comment: I assume interface builder does the [UIImage imageNamed:@"Find"]; and does the @2x for free? correct?

Comment: Yes, images added in Interface Builder also have the automatic @2x behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

[Detect retina screen/iPhone 4 in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272752/detect-retina-screen-iphone-4-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `imageNamed:` method of `UIImage` the @2x business is handled for you.

Otherwise you can check the scale of the screen as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294100/how-to-differentiate-between-iphone4-and-iphone-3)

Answer (score 1):

If your application is running on (I believe) iOS 4.2 or greater and the images are PNG files you can replace you calls of:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Find.png"];
```

with simply:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Find"];
```

On the later versions of the OS `imageNamed` attempts to treat the incoming parameter as a root name to an image instead of the specific image name itself. In such a case it has the intelligence built-in to load the graphic most appropriate for the device.