# How to detect the Retina Display in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, retina-display

Just that question I want to detect the retina display in my MonoTouch app. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are already [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272752/detect-retina-screen-iphone-4-in-iphone-sdk) for ObjectiveC but here's a C# version:

```
 bool retina = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale > 1.0);
```

That will work for the newer iPhone and iPod Touch and I suspect (will know in less than two weeks) for the **new** iPad.

Jason's approach will work too and can be attractive if you need to know several hardware related features (e.g. retina + camera).

Comment: interesting - I assumed you had to check the device type to know this