# How to migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in iphone in which i am using most of the static images in the background as an image in the background image it self.Means a single background image including all the staic things.now i want to migrate to iphone 5 also.Now i am using an image of 640*960 as the background image.if i change that to 640*1136 then when it used in 4serieses of iphone the image will shrink i think.Let it i am fixing the frame size by checking the screeen.Can anybody help me how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To know, what kind of image You should use (for iPad 768x1024,  for iPhone 320x480, etc..)
You can detect device, and then set corresponding image.

You can distinguish between iPad/Retina/iPhone using this SO article:

[Detect retina screen/iPhone 4 in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272752/detect-retina-screen-iphone-4-in-iphone-sdk/7607087#7607087)

You can detect iPhone 5 using example in this SO article:

[How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

If you have only portrait supported, You can check using this simple method:

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    //iPhone, iPhone retina
}
else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024)
{
    //iPad, iPad retina
}
else //568 height
{
    //iPhone 5
}
```

And of course - as **Valeriy Van** mentioned, You need Default-568h@2x.png image added to your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between image resolution and size of UIImageView. Image will be rescaled or positioned inside view bounds depending on contentMode property.

What you need first - add Default-568h@2x.png image of 640x1136 as Launch Image for Retina 4 inch. If springs and struts of your views are set right, everything will work as granted.

Comment: i didnt get u?springs and sports means?

Comment: It is about autoresizingMask property. They work like springs and struts and in Interface builder look similar.

Comment: i sd if i set a frame size according to  (320 ,480) with an image with a reselution 1136*640 it will shrinked?right?

Comment: It depends on contentMode property. In most cases yes, it will be rescaled.