# How to get image DPI when selected from photo library in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, dpi

I am trying to find out the **DPI** of the selected image from photo library but getting **(null)**.

Using below code.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData * imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.0);
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef) imgData, NULL);
CFDictionaryRef imageDict = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(src, 0, NULL);

// Print image dictionary
NSString *dpiHeight = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageDict, @"DPIHeight");
NSString *dpiWidth = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageDict, @"DPIWidth");   
NSLog(@"DPIHeight:%@ DPIWidth: %@",dpiHeight, dpiWidth);

}
```

is it correct ? can i get DPI from image data ?
is there any other possibilities ?

Can any one help me will highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/23943401/5362916

Comment: Have you debugged that method to see if anything is `nil`?  Also it looks to me like you have a memory leak after using `CGImageSourceCreateWithData()` and `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex()` and not releasing the returned objects?

Comment: @trojanfoe ya you are correct how can solve this ?

Comment: Nope.  Have you done what I suggested?

Comment: Ya debugged it and getting nil at dpiHeight ,dpiWidth only

Comment: @ChandanReddy OK that just sounds like the DPI information is not contained in the image.  See the answer I linked as duplicate.

Comment: @trojanfoe can you check this  [link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/get-image-data-including-depth-color-model-dpi-and-more.html)  you can get DPI of image which one is not getting by using above method.

Comment: The image doesn't always contain that information.  You cannot obtain something which is not there.

Comment: Finally  got it check this [Github link](https://github.com/foundry/UIImageMetadata)